# Swift loop through array of dictionaries and create a new one

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm struggling on getting a new array of dictionaries with conditioned 10 elements out of 80.

here is sample of students json:

```
{
    "id": 111,
    "name": "John",
    "gender": "male",
    "grade": 80,
    "extraCredit": 20
},
{
    "id": 112,
    "name": "Jenny",
    "gender": "female",
    "grade": 85,
    "extraCredit": 5
}
```

and my struct:

```
struct StudentData: Decodable {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
  var grade: Int
  var extraCredit: Int
}
```

I need to calculate each student's grade to get final grade and display top 10
here is my code to loop through:

```
var newStudentData = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()
for student in studentData {
  let finalGrade = student.grade + (student.extraCredit * 0.5)
  if finalGrade > 88 {
     newStudentData.append(student)   // error on cannot convert value type of ’StudentData’ to expected argument type ‘[String: Any]
  }
}
```

what did I do wrong? or is there a better way?

Comment: How is your StudentData defined, I assume it is `[StudentData]`?

Comment: yes, studentData is [StudentData]

Comment: Ok, I guess you have your answer then from Gereon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newStudentData` is a dictionary (why?), but you're appending instances of `StudentData` to it. This won't work.

That said, I would probably rewrite this like so:

```
struct StudentData: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let grade: Int
    let extraCredit: Int

    var finalGrade: Int {
        return self.grade + self.extraCredit / 2
    }
}

var students = [StudentData]()
// fill students array here

let beat88 = students.filter { $0.finalGrade > 88 }
let top10 = beat88.sorted { $0.finalGrade > $1.finalGrade }.prefix(10)
```